# How to find out which mount argument is invalid?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

When getting `mount error(22): Invalid argument`, how to find out which of the many arguments is the invalid one?

It seems like `-v` option doesn't give more info about that, is there a mount log that is more detailed?

Comment: Add the actual command that you are using to your question.

Comment: I added "Ubuntu" tag, as for the command it's just "mount -a"

Comment: The mount options are listed in `/etc/fstab`,  what does the line for this particular mountpoint look like?

Comment: Oh, I already know which option was wrong (from educated guessing), but I was wondering if there was a better way to find out this kind of stuff in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dmesg` shows the kernel log.

Sometimes this has more information, sometimes it does not.

There is a future kernel interface that might help.  It might help in that it will allow setting options in a series of individual calls - e.g. so I hope that if you pass a number which was way out of range, the kernel might tell you as soon as you pass that option.  Perhaps the most interesting part of the new interface is that it will allow filesystems to directly return a specific error message.  At the moment, they can only return one of a few set error numbers, such as your error 22 (EINVAL / "Invalid argument").

[A new API for mounting filesystems](https://lwn.net/Articles/753473/) -- LWN.net, May 4, 2018.

This API has seen some continued work in the past few months.